# Is it possible to insert separator in midnight commander menu?

Tags: midnight-commander

I want to insert some items into mc menu (which is opened by F2) grouped together. Is it possible to insert some sort of separator before them or put them into some submenu?

Answer (score 2):

Probably, not.

```
The format of the menu file is very simple. Lines that start with anything but
space or tab are considered entries for the menu (in order to be able to use
it like a hot key, the first character should be a letter). All the lines that
start with a space or a tab are the commands that will be executed when the
entry is selected.
```

But MC allows you to make multiple menu entries with same shortcut and title, so you can make a menu entry that looks like separator and does nothing, like:

```
a hello
  echo world
- --------
b world
  echo hello
- --------
c superuser
  ls /
```

This will look like:

[image: menu with separators]